# Подскажите по регулярному выражению

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

День добрый. Подскажите как выбрать можно ип из строки ниже, не беря слеш.
Сама строка имеет вид:

```
'/root/test.py', '--action', 'on', '--login', 'test-login', '--password', '4553', '--shape', '100', '--net', '10.11.0.2/255.255.255.255', '--net', '10.3.101.3/255.255.255.255'
```

Я составлял регулярное вида:

```
([\w/]\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})
```

Тогда я получаю целиком ип + слеш + маска

Если `(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}[\/])` , получую ИП но со слешем.
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Спасибо, попробовал на сайте, все выбирает как надо. Спасибо за помошь.

Comment: Уберите "решено" из заголовка, оформите решение ответом и отметьте его как принятный

Comment: @ipatev_nn, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: @ipatev_nn предположение оказалось верным, оформите ответом

Comment: @ipatev_nn, во-первых, ответ, во-вторых, автор уже сказал, что работает.